# why am I getting NaN value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why valInt is returning NaN and how I can fix it so that it stores deposit value.

*Edit: Made some changes since posting. I'm still getting NaN for the balance.

//JS

```
`function depositMoney () {
//Select the balance amount
let acctBal = $('.check-balance')
let chkBal = acctBal
let chkBalVal = chkBal.html()
console.log(chkBalVal)

//Needs to accept input.
let input = $('.input')
let depositVal = parseInt(input.val())
console.log('Deposit amount: ' + depositVal)

//Collect info from balance.
let valInt = parseInt(chkBalVal)
console.log('Current balance is: ' + valInt)

//Displaying the checking amount.
let sumTot = (depositVal + valInt)
console.log('Total here:' + sumTot)
acctBal.html('$' + (depositVal + valInt))
}`
```

// HTML

```
`<div id="checking" class="account">
  <h2>Checking</h2>
  <div class="check-balance">$0</div>
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="enter an amount" />
  <input class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
  <input class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
  </div>`
```

Comment: It looks like you're setting `acctBal` to a jQuery selector, not a numeric value. Did you mean to use `$('.check-balance').val()`?

Comment: change that line to `let chkBal = acctBal.val()`

Comment: valInt is referring to a jQuery object, adding  `.val()` will return the value needed.  `parseInt(chkBal.val())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let valInt = parseInt(chkBal)
```

This code is trying to convert `chkBal` to number, where `chkBal` is exactly like `acctBal` - a jQuery object.

You have to take the value that stored in jQuery DOM object with the command [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), and then convert the result to a number by modifying the line beginning with `let chkBal =` like so:

```
let chkBal = acctBal.val();
```